# Performing calculation based off multiple rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Set up an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, False, np.nan, np.nan], [5, False, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, True, 'a', 'b'],[np.nan,True,'b','a']],
                   columns=['value', 'IsRatio', 'numerator','denominator'],index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

| index | value | IsRatio | numerator | denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | False | nan | nan |
| b | 5 | False | nan | nan |
| c | nan | True | a | b |
| d | nan | True | b | a |

For rows where IsRatio is True, I would like to lookup the values for the numerator and denominator, and calculate a ratio.

For a single row I can use .loc

```
numerator_name = df.loc['c','numerator']
denominator_name = df.loc['c','denominator']
df.loc['c','value'] = int(df.loc[numerator_name]['value'])/int(df.loc[denominator_name]['value'])
```

This will calculate the ratio for a single row

| index | value | IsRatio | numerator | denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | False | nan | nan |
| b | 5 | False | nan | nan |
| c | 2 | True | a | b |
| d | nan | True | b | a |

How can I generalise this to all rows? I think I might need an apply function but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to apply your computation to each row (mind the `axis=1` input argument):

```py
df['value'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: int(df.loc[x.numerator]['value']) / int(df.loc[x.denominator]['value'])
    if x.IsRatio else x.value,
    axis=1
)
```

The result is the following:

```sh
  value IsRatio numerator denominator
a    10   False       nan         nan
b     5   False       nan         nan
c     2    True         a           b
d   0.5    True         b           a
```

**Note**: you should remove `np.array` from the creation of the example DataFrame, otherwise the `IsRatio` column has type `str`. So `df` should be defined as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, False, np.nan, np.nan], [5, False, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, True, 'a', 'b'],[np.nan,True,'b','a']],
                   columns=['value', 'IsRatio', 'numerator','denominator'],index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

Otherwise, if `IsRatio` column is actually of type `str`, you should modify the previous code as following:

```py
df['value'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: int(df.loc[x.numerator]['value']) / int(df.loc[x.denominator]['value'])
    if x.IsRatio == 'True' else x.value,
    axis=1
)

  value IsRatio numerator denominator
a    10   False       nan         nan
b     5   False       nan         nan
c     2    True         a           b
d   0.5    True         b           a
```

Answer (score 1):

To do as a vectorised solution numpy `where()` is a good solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10, False, np.nan, np.nan], [5, False, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, True, 10, 5],[np.nan,True,30,10]]),
                   columns=['value', 'IsRatio', 'numerator','denominator'],index=['a','b','c','d'])

# df.assign(v=np.where)
df.IsRatio = df.IsRatio.astype(bool)
df.assign(v=np.where(df.IsRatio, df.numerator/df.denominator, df.value))
```

|  | value | IsRatio | numerator | denominator | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | False | nan | nan | 10 |
| b | 5 | False | nan | nan | 5 |
| c | nan | True | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| d | nan | True | 30 | 10 | 3 |